# Настройка товаров

Tags: woocommerce

На странице "Магазин" вдруг стал отображаться только один товар и переход на вторую страницу и т.д. Т.е. на каждой странице по одному товару. кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? И как можно решить?

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте в админке "Настройки->Чтение->На страницах блога отображать не более". По умолчанию, количество товаров, выводимых на странице, задается там.

Кроме того, есть такой сниппет, вставьте его в конец functions.php

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'new_loop_shop_per_page', 20 );

function new_loop_shop_per_page( $cols ) {
    // $cols содержит текущее значение товаров на странице
    // Верните число с указанием нужного количества товаров
    $cols = 12;
    return $cols;
}
```